# Documentation about Laravel hasAny()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Does anybody seen a Laravel 5.5 documentation how to use the hasAny() method on a request?

Answer (score 0):

You pass an array of keys to a MessageBag to see if any of those keys exist:

```
$keys = ['email', 'password'];

if($errors->hasAny($keys)) {
    //if either email, password, or both exist it will hit this conditional
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The request do not provide any `hasAny()` method since the request input is a `Symfpny\Component\ParameterBag` instance and it does not provide the method you are looking for. `hasAny()` is present in `Illuminate\Support\MessageBag` but it is not retrievable from the request itself. To check if the request input has any of the requested keys you have to iterate over all the request parameters and perform the check using the `has()` method.

You could do this with a one liner, a bit raw but it works:

```
if(count(array_intersect(['foo', 'bar'], $request->keys()) > 0) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

or you have to loop all over your 'any' parameters:

```
$any = ['foo', 'bar'];

$check = false;
foreach($any as $item) {

   if($request->has($item)) $check = true;
}

if($check) {
   // do your stuff
}
```